# Exporting Object Models/ Exporting Individual Models

Tags: modeling, objects

I'm wondering if there is a method to export models individually from a scene or file into Unity3d.  Basically I've made a collection of them (models) and when I exported them into Unity they were not.... Standalone(? pardon my poor choice for terminology).

Comment: In the export window you have an option to export selected only.

Comment: Just saw your reply; Thanks :). I'll give it a try